# how to use BlockingQueues

Tags: java

I am having a problem with BlockingQueues. The size of the queue comes back as 1 for the first loop and then it is zero after so there is something there. But the variables 'as' is null.

```
public class Board extends JPanel {
    private myClass mc;
    private Thread combatThread;
    final BlockingQueue<myClass> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<myClass>();

    public Board() {
        mc = new myClass();
        mc.add(1);
        mc.add(2);
        combatThread = new Thread(new cThread(queue));

        test();
    }

    public void test() {    
        try {
            queue.add(mc);
        } catch(Exception e1) {}
        combatThread.start();
    }


    public class cThread implements Runnable {
        private myClass as;

        public cThread(BlockingQueue queue) {

        }

        public void run() {
            while( true ){
                try {
                    as = queue.poll(); //as is null
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [`queue.poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll--) returns `null` immediately if the queue is empty. If you want the thread to wait until there's something in the queue, use [`take()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take--) instead of `poll()`.

Comment: sorry I should rephrase. If I print 'as' it should contain 1 and 2, but it prints null.

Comment: In other words, as.array[1] throws a null pointer error.

Comment: So,  Jesper's comment.

Comment: Note that you are only adding **one** object to the queue, in the `test()` method. I don't know what `myClass.add()` does, but you're only creating one `myClass` object that's put on the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In constructor

```
public Board()
```

you create one object - mc, and give to it two values (1,2)

in method

```
public void test()
```

you add this one object to queue

```
queue.add(mc);
```

so when thread starts, the queue contains just one (myClass)mc instance reference, and this mc object should contain 1 and 2 values (I not sure because you not give MyClass source). First iteration in

```
  while( true ){
                try {
                    as = queue.poll(); //as is null
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
```

will assign "as" variable reference to "mc". But how to know is this object any kind of Queue, why you think asArray method should work? Do you implement it or inherit somewhere? I suggest you are not. But if you ask about BlockingQueue you are mess.

myClass - here you wrong. Class name should start with capital letter. Read about Java name conventions.

This constructor confuse too, it does nothing, why you use it?

```
 public cThread(BlockingQueue queue) {

        }
```

I think you should read something like http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/02/producer-consumer-design-pattern-with.html, to see how BlockingQueue works, but also I see you are not understand some basics, may be you should start with some beginners books about variable references, inheritance, collections and after that return to this task.